# Posting and parsing data sent from JQuery to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, request

I'm trying to use JQuery to pass a data structure that looks similar to the one below to a php script:

```
{
  "shopping":
    [
      {
         "type": "online",
         "mood": 9 
      },
      {
         "type": "mood",
         "mood": 4
      }
    ],
   "researching":
     [
      {
         "type": "online",
         "mood": 3 
      },
      {
         "type": "library",
         "mood": 1
      }
     ]
}
```

This data in the JSON changes based on forms and sliders a user manipulates, and then the JSON is sent asynchrounously with a submit button. I am having trouble figuring out how to use JQuery to submit this request, and how to have PHP parse it. I would like to send this data using the POST method. Right now, I'm using:

```
$.post('server/dataInput.php',submissions, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Where submissions is the JSON object, however this doesn't seem to be working. I also dont' know how I would then parse this JSON on PHP's end.

Comment: "this doesn't seem to be working" --- this is absolutely not informative. Send that json object and show us `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: The "$.post" not working needs more detailing as to what is not working -- the path 'server/dataInput.php' is relative, so maybe you are posting to a different URL than the one you are expecting -- is the a web server log file you can look at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using jquery 1.4.0+ `json_decode` is not necessary. Your data will be received in PHP as an array.

**Example:**

*JS fragment:*

```
var testData = {
    "shopping": [
      {
         "type": "online",
         "mood": 9 
      },
      {
         "type": "mood",
         "mood": 4
      }
    ],
    "researching": [
      {
         "type": "online",
         "mood": 3 
      },
      {
         "type": "library",
         "mood": 1
      }
    ]
};

function sendTest() {
    $.post('test.php', testData, function(data) { console.log(data); });
}
```

Call `sendTest`...

*test.php:*

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);
```

And your success function will display what `test.php` outputted:

```
array(2)
{
  ["shopping"]=> array(2)
  {
    [0]=> array(2)
    {
      ["type"]=> string(6) "online"
      ["mood"]=> string(1) "9"
    }
    [1]=> array(2)
    {
      ["type"]=> string(4) "mood"
      ["mood"]=> string(1) "4"
    }
  }

  ["researching"]=> array(2)
  {
    [0]=> array(2)
    {
      ["type"]=> string(6) "online"
      ["mood"]=> string(1) "3"
    }
    [1]=> array(2)
    {
      ["type"]=> string(7) "library"
      ["mood"]=> string(1) "1"
    }
  }
}
```

So, everything works out-of-the-box! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the PHP [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to unpack the JSON data?

Comment: The data isn't sent as a *json object string*, but as a json object, so it is already parsed